# Printing VF component

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object that includes custom fields, and our consultant just built us a beautiful Visualforce (VF) component that embeds into a section of the page.  Our only problem comes when we try to print.  When we click Printable View, everything looks great.

[image: Printable View]

Then we click Print This Page, and while the custom fields on the page print just fine, the VF component cuts off to the right.

[image: Print This Page]

Can anyone tell me if there is a way around this?  Printing to a printer or PDF creator does the exact same thing.  Skipping Printable View and printing straight from the page also cuts the VF component off.  We're uncertain why the Printable View looks great and once we try to print we lose our functionality.

Comment: Have you tried to change the page orientation (Potrait to Landscape)?

Comment: Thank you for your question, but yes, we've tried switching orientation.  The only difference between Portrait and Landscape is that the text is larger in Landscape.  Unfortunately, we don't get more fields by changing the orientation.

Answer (score 2):

The developer of your page needs to add some additional CSS to your page using the following kind of syntax:

```
@media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
  }
  @media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
  @media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
  }
```

He'll need to adjust it to fit your particular code and situation so your pages will print properly.

Comment: Thank you.  We tried adding this code to the page, and it didn't help my print issue.  The issue seems to lie in my system's print settings.  We discovered yesterday that my consultant, several of his coworkers, and my boss can all print the page just fine.  Our internal IT department is troubleshooting my print settings to see why only my instances of IE11 and Chrome are having issues with printing.

Comment: The above code would need to be customized to your page, not used "as is". It's also possible that the component needs to be wrapped in a block element container or the page itself has too wide of margin settings if you're using custom css (or your specific printer doesn't support wide enough margins) for the page. Again, that's where using @media settings can be helpful as pixels vs points, ems or `%` are different for screen than paper media.